# What type parameter will be used if I call a generic method with a raw type as argument?

Tags: java, generics

I'm just curious what's the generated inferred T type when passing a raw to a T type. It does compile but with a warning.

```
public class GenericMethodInference {

    static <T> void test5(List<T t>){} // clause (5)

    public static void main(String [] args) {

    List e = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    test5(e);  // clause (6) // ok but with warning.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a raw type to a generic type will assume no generic constraint (which will default to Object) but remove any compile-time type safety guarantees that might otherwise have existed.

> But you cannot assign a raw to a `List <Object>` since it has been
>   erased

It sounds like there is a fundamental misunderstanding of type erasure here. The raw type *is the end result of a generic type*. You specified `List<Integer>`, the compiler verifies against that type information and then removes the `<Integer>` portion of that, inserting casts to Integer as appropriate from actions against the raw type of List.

That means that these two retrieval operations are exactly the same.

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integerList.add(5);

Integer i = integerList.get(0); 
Integer ii = (Integer)((List)integerList).get(0);
```

For example, the following is legal. This only gives a warning (instead of causing a compiler error or runtime error) because we're acting on Object and are still within the appropriate bounds of the contained type.

```
List<Object> objects = (List)integerList;
Object value = objects.get(0);
System.out.println(value);
```

It will print out 5. Where the type system helps is if you try to do something like this.

```
List<String> badStringList = integerList;
```

It will give you a compiler error stating that there is a type mismatch. Using the raw type directly, however, will throw all of that type safety away and rely solely on your judgement for the correct types that should be used. This allows you to easily shoot yourself in the foot if you get it wrong.

```
List<String> badStringList = (List)integerList;
String badValue = badStringList.get(0); //ClassCastException is thrown at runtime
```

Comment: List<Object> objects = (List)integerList; Why does this gives a warning? This is where my confusion is. I can understand the warning if it is List<String> objects = (List)integerList; or even List<Integer> objects = (List)integerList; But Object is the highest superclass here. So i'm a bit confused

Comment: It gives a warning because you are casting a generic type (which _has_ additional compile-time type information) to a raw type (which has none). It's legal (and has to be for legacy reasons, as irreputable said) but it's not advised. You are essentially saying to the compiler, "You know that List you were managing type changes on? Don't worry about that anymore, I'll do that myself" which produces a warning as the compiler says "Hey, do you realize you're doing this? You could screw this up pretty badly".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have any problem with the warning from a generic type to raw type. It is the assignment from the raw back to List <Object> which gives a warning that confuses me. Look at the comment i put on irreputable section

Comment: The same also applies the other way. By taking a raw type and imposing generic information on it, the compiler has no way of verifying that the type conversion is correct and gives you a warning. The conversion is 'unchecked' in that sense. You can suppress that warning if you're absolutely sure that what you're doing is correct and you don't want the compiler to complain, but it's another way of the compiler saying "Hey, you might be about to do something you'll regret".

Comment: For example, if we split out the conversion in my last example, you will get a warning on `List rawList = integerList;` because you're removing generic information and an error on `List<String> badStringList = rawList;` because the compiler cannot verify that your conversion is correct (and in this case, it most certainly is not).

Comment: I think i got the answer. Reason why raw to List <?> is permissible and List <Object> is not (eventhough Object is the highest superclass) is because <?> prevents adding of records while an unbounded type references allows adding of records - hence might cause type safety issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is done for backward compatibility. Before generics,

```
static void test5(List t){}

List e = ...;
test5(e);
```

When generics was introduced, they need to generify `List` and methods like `test5()`, without asking all usages like `test5(e)` to be rewritten and recompiled. So `test5(e)` must still be valid.

This is achieved by relaxing type inference rules and method signature matching rules.

Inference: `List << List<T>` this can't hold in the subtyping sense; however inference rules just ignore it; `T` has no constraints, and simply picked to be `Object`

Method signature: `List e` is is not subtype of the method parameter type `List<Object>`, however it is acceptable by "method invocation conversion", which allows "unchecked conversion" from `List` to `List<Whatever>`; the "unchecked conversion" triggers the mandatory compiler warning.

---

This is only of historical interest; no programmer today should care. Since obviously there's no way for `List` to be a subtype of `List<T>` whatever `T` is, we should practically treat it as error, and never write code like that (even though it compiles). A `List<?> e` would work.

Comment: I wish i could also check yours as an answer. How do i check more than 1 response as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the inferred type would be Object

Comment: But you cannot assign a raw to a List <Object> since it has been erased.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class GenericMethodInference {

    static <T> void test5(List<T> xx) {
        System.out.println(xx.getClass());  //class java.util.ArrayList
        System.out.println(xx.get(0).getClass()); //class java.lang.Integer
        System.out.println(xx.get(1).getClass()); //class java.lang.String
    } // clause (5)

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List e = new ArrayList<Long>();
        e.add(1);
        e.add("2");
        test5(e); // clause (6) // ok but with warning.
    }
}
```

This confirms that the type inferred is Object type.

Answer (score 0):

T is a generic one. It can accept any object.